# Why is nil preprocessed to ((void *)0) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, clang, c-preprocessor

Using Xcode 8.3.2, if I use `nil` in an Objective-C file and choose Product > Perform Action > Preprocess "MySourceFile.m", `nil` turns into `((void *)0)`. I have a couple of questions:

1. If `nil` is a part of the language, why does the preprocessor do anything to it at all? Why doesn't the compilation step accept `nil` directly?
2. Why does `nil` turn into `((void *)0)` when the whole point of it is to be a null **object** pointer? Why isn't it preprocessed to something like `((id)0)`, as sources like [this one](http://nshipster.com/nil/) define it?

Comment: Is this true for a brand new project? Could the project you're seeing this in include some weird header which `#define`s `nil`? Or build settings that define such a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Part of the language" doesn't have to mean "part of the compiler". For instance, the C  standard forces `NULL` to be a macro. There is no Objective-C standard, so Objective-C implementers can do just about what they want. What's important is that, when you take the entire programming environment, you have access to a `nil` token that represents the absence of an object.

`nil` wasn't always the same as `NULL`: it [used to be defined as just 0](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-208/runtime/objc.h.auto.html), then around 2007 it was [changed to `__DARWIN_NULL`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/objc.h.auto.html), and in recent versions it'll be `nullptr` in Objective-C++ mode and `__DARWIN_NULL` otherwise. (`__DARWIN_NULL` comes from `<sys/_types.h>`.)

Xcode is a bit obnoxious about finding the definition of a "pseudo-keyword". I find that for macros that Xcode treats as a keyword (like `nil` and `NULL`), the best way to find where they are defined is to redefine them and look at the error message.

```
#define nil 0
        ^
foo/main.m:29:9: warning: 'nil' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]

In module 'Foundation' imported from foo/main.m:9:
In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /.../Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In module 'Dispatch' imported from /.../Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15:
In module 'os_object' imported from /.../include/dispatch/dispatch.h:66:
In module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /.../include/os/object.h:99:
/.../include/objc/objc.h:108:12: note: previous definition is here
#   define nil __DARWIN_NULL
           ^
```

Comment: This is great information, thanks. Do you have any insight into my second question?

Comment: @Luke, I can't really think of any reason, sorry. "Nil is a class, nil is an object and NULL is anything else" is something that I've argued for in the past, but my outlook now is that it's hard to justify three different constants for the same value, especially when any of them could work for all three's use cases. There's a point to be made that appropriately-typed `nil`/`Nil` could be beneficial for template parameter deduction in Objective-C++, but that's pretty much it. Nobody writes `[nil objectAtIndex:0]` or `[Nil alloc]`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Neither `nil` or `NULL` are part of the (Objective-)C language *per se*, that is they are not *keywords* but rather are pre-defined constants/macros in the libraries/frameworks.
2. This comes from the C Standard:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

and it is conventional to always include the cast to make it clear the result is the *null pointer constant*. It is also convention to use `NULL` for C pointer types and `nil` for Objective-C object reference types, they both expand to the null pointer constant.